# For loop using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, where-clause

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe that labels animals that are domesticated with a 1. I'm using a for loop, but for some reason, the loop only picks up the last item in the `pets` list. `dog`, `cat`, and `gerbil` should all be assigned a 1 under the `domesticated` column. Anyone have a fix for this or a better approach?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'creature': ['dog', 'cat', 'gerbil', 'mouse', 'donkey']
    })

pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'gerbil']

for pet in pets:
    df['domesticated'] = np.where(df['creature']==pet, 1, 0)

df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting all non gerbil to `0` in your last loop iteration. That is, when `pet` is `gerbil` in your last iteration, ALL entries that are not equal to `gerbil` will correspond to `0`. This includes entries that are `dog` or `cat`. You should check all values in `pets` at once. Try this:

```
df['domesticated'] = df['creature'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in pets else 0)
```

If you want to stick with `np.where`:

```
df['domesticated'] = np.where(df['creature'].isin(pets), 1, 0)
```

Comment: this is great. I'll check mark this when I'm allowed to. Do you know why the for loop doesn't work in this case? I include `dog`, `cat`, and `gerbil` in the `pets` list, so I thought iterating over that list would work fine.

Comment: I updated my post with more detail. The idea is the last iteration overwrites everything from before so you are essentially just checking for values that are equal to `gerbil`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is every loop resets your results.

```
df['domesticated'] = df.isin(pets).astype(int)

  creature  domesticated
0      dog             1
1      cat             1
2   gerbil             1
3    mouse             0
4   donkey             0
```